# Cloud9 (C9) AWS EC2 .htaccess being ignored

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, cloud9

I have created a new C9 AWS instance, and my .htaccess file is being ignored.

**Here are the file contents:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

**Here is what I have done:**

- I have changed my httpd.conf to Allow All.
- I have restarted the server after making changes to httpd.conf file
- I have tried putting garbage in the .htaccess file to test it
- I have changed the default directory to match what runs in c9

**Here is a picture of my httpd.conf:**

[image]

Any help with this would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing two things to fix this issue:

1. Changing the listening port in the httpd.conf to 8080
2. Chmod all directories to 755 `find /home/ec2-user/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`

Answer (score 0):

Please check as you need to change the file from following location as a root user:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: I had already changed AllowOveride All in this file with no luck.